# ProFTPd hashing algorhythm - password audit with hashcat

Tags: hash, proftpd, hashcat

I'm running a small root server which has several tasks automated through ftp connections.
I'm using proFTPd 1.3.4d in standalone mode with mod_auth_file.c as authentication module. So I'm using an AuthUserFile, not the standard passwd file from the server.
I'm usually generating the content of the auth file with the ftpasswd utility.
Latest weeks, I get a lot of automated scripts trying to bruteforcing into my ftp. So I want to regularly check my authfile entries against a local dictionary password file to check if the passwords are strong enough and maybe generate new ones once in a while.

entries in the auth file look like this (slightly modified):

username:ecEg9vyd5eAi.:18000:18000::/home/ftp/username:/bin/false

What kind of hash is "ecEg9vyd5eAi." and can I verify it with hashcat and a dictionary?

regards
Dave

Answer (score 2):

It's DEScrypt, use can use hashcat with option -m 1500 to crack it